# Checking for all Elements in a Set in Haskell using syntactic sugar

Tags: list, haskell, syntax, list-comprehension, unique

I try to remove the Integer duplicates of a List of `(String, Int)`, where I am guaranteed that there is no `String` duplicate.

Is it possible to evaluate something like this in Haskell:

[image]

I tried:

```
[(a,b) | (a,b) <- bs, (c,k) <- bs, ((k == b) <= (a == c))]
```

but this does not yet work.

Edit: I am well aware, that you can achieve that using more complex syntax. For example by recursively searching the List for each elements duplicates...

Comment: You have a "forall" formula in the orignal set, so you can't simply translate that as a generator `(c,k) <- bs`. You could instead use the function `all` to check all the pairs.

Comment: @ Niclas yep, I was completely off base here. :) got my wires crossed. will delete the answer. your code for `removeDuplicate` already does this, so perhaps you should post it as the answer and accept it! (just name it `removeDuplicates` or even better, `uniquesOnly`). when you do, @ ping me here so I can up-vote!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64944978/is-there-a-nubby-analogue-for-unique-in-haskell is closely related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(NB: this is a completely new version of this answer. Previous was totally off-base.)

To follow your mathematical set comprehension more closely, we can tweak the definition in your answer as

```
uniquesOnly :: (Eq a, Eq b) => [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]
uniquesOnly bs = 
   [(a,b) | (a,b) <- bs, 
            [(c,d) | (c,d) <- bs, d == b] ==
            [(a,d) | (c,d) <- bs, d == b]]
```

"for all (c,d) in bs such that d==b it follows c==a".

`uniquesOnly [(1,1),(2,2),(3,1)]` returns `[(2,2)]`.

Comment: Why take 1? Would this not take the first element and only the first element? http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/take_f.html

Comment: yes, that's the point of it, no? it's what you wanted, and the example run proves it. :) you wanted to keep just one of the duplicates, so the first is accepted and all the others get rejected. you said it's guaranteed there are no duplicate Strings. that's why it's working. the first snippet, with `nubBy`, works regardless, but you wanted "syntax sugar". :)

Comment: Ohhh. I see. I have written my question a bit off. I think - maybe I have a twist in my head - the mathematical equation deletes both, the original and the duplicate since there are no "originals". So I do not mean "remove " duplicates, but remove all elements for which the equation does not hold. Which should be (1,1) and (3, 1) if I am not wrong.

Comment: well my post answers the set notation specification. for new code, what's the question? it already does what you ask for, it only keeps the elements which had no duplicates, in the original, and does it nicely. see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64944978/is-there-a-nubby-analogue-for-unique-in-haskell) recent question which asks for the same thing as your new one.

Comment: I am sorry. But I just do not see how your code evaluates my mathematical equation. 
Let S = {(1,1), (2,2), (3,1)}, the resulting set B should be {(2,2)}
Am I wrong?

Comment: yep, I was completely off base here. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution:

For example, I have made up this equivalent statement:

```
removeDuplicates ::  [(String, Int)] -> [(String, Int)]
removeDuplicates bs = 
   [(a,b) | (a,b) <- bs, 
            length [(c,d) | (c,d) <- bs, d == b] == 1]
```

But this is not the same statement only an equal one.

Comment: `length` should always be avoided if at all possible. here, you can replace it by `[_] <- [[(c,d) | (c,d) <- bs, d == b]]`.

Comment: I've tweaked your definition to follow the set comprehension more closely, and edited my  answer.

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers don't take advantage of the guarantee that the strings are unique or the fact that `Int` is ordered. Here's one that does.

```
import Data.List (sortBy, groupBy)
import Data.Function (on)

uniquesOnly :: Ord b => [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]
uniquesOnly ps
  = [ p
    | [p] <- groupBy ((==) `on` snd) .
             sortBy (compare `on` snd) $ ps ]
```